# How Sarada was able to awaken Sharingan?

Tags: naruto, naruto-gaiden

According to definition of Sharingan:

> When an Uchiha **experiences a powerful emotional condition** with regards
>   to a person precious to them, their brain releases a special form of
>   chakra that affects the optic nerves, transforming the eyes into
>   Sharingan

So my question is that how Sarada Uchiha was able to awaken Sharingan? I mean is there any event occured to Sarada due which she was able to awaken Sharingan. Is it mentioned anywhere in anime or manga which tells how Sarada got his Sharingan or about any emotional event she faced?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the wiki,

> The excitement of getting to be in the same room as him (Sasuke) causes her sharingan to awaken

So the fact she would finally get to meet her father causes such a powerful emotional response her Sharingan awakens

http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sarada_Uchiha